# Gem install Rails fails on Windows: too many connection resets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows

I am trying to install Rails. But it is giving same error: too many connections reset. I tried reading articles to solve it,but still no solution. I am not using any proxy server.

It starts fetching a gems but none of it are completed. It continuously gives following error:

> too many connection resets (http://cachefly.mirrors.rubygems.org/gems/activemodel-3.0.5.gem)

I have tried all solutions given on Stack Overflow. But still no solution. Is there a one click installer for Rails as there is for Ruby?

Comment: Do you have tried [rails installer](http://railsinstaller.org/)?

Comment: No i haven't tried it because i want to run on rails 3.0.5 and this rails installer is 3.2.Thx though...

Comment: I tried rails installer,but once i create a new project with rails new xyz, then it prompts for bundle install, when i do bundle install then Fetching source index for https://rubygems.org/ sticks forever.What is the problem,i need a solution quickly plz.

Comment: And now i cant post any questions on stackoverflow,i am banned for asking the same question,but i already tried all the solutions given in the solution of gem install rails.How can i be banned.So unfair of stackovrflow, i am in real need of help,and they ban me